# Unable to read data from kafka topic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

I'm a beginner in kafka. Trying to code a spark application to read data from a kafka topic created. Kafka topic1 is up & running.

Is there any problem with the code provided below:

```
    val kafka_bootstrap_servers = "localhost:9092"

    val users_df = spark.read
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers)
      .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name)
      .load()

    val users_df_1 = users_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "CAST(timestamp AS TIMESTAMP)")

    val user_schema = StructType(
      List(
        StructField("RecordNumber", IntegerType, true),
        StructField("Zipcode", StringType, true),
        StructField("ZipCodeType", StringType, true),
        StructField("City", StringType, true),
        StructField("State", StringType, true),
        StructField("LocationType", StringType, true),
        StructField("Lat", StringType, true),
        StructField("Long", StringType, true),
        StructField("Xaxis", StringType, true),
        StructField("Yaxis", StringType, true),
        StructField("Zaxis", StringType, true),
        StructField("WorldRegion", StringType, true),
        StructField("Country", StringType, true),
        StructField("LocationText", StringType, true),
        StructField("Location", StringType, true),
        StructField("Decommisioned", StringType, true)
      )
    )

    val users_df_2 = users_df_1.select(from_json(col("RecordNumber"), user_schema)
      .as("user_detail"), col("Zipcode"))

  val users_df_3 = users_df_2.select(col = "user_detail.*", "Zipcode")

    users_df_3.printSchema()
    users_df_3.show(numRows = 10, truncate = false)

    spark.stop()
    println("Apache spark application completed.")



  }


}
```

**json data sample below**

```
{"RecordNumber":76511,"Zipcode":27007,"ZipCodeType":"STANDARD","City":"ASH HILL","State":"NC","LocationType":"NOT ACCEPTABLE","Lat":36.4,"Long":-80.56,"Xaxis":0.13,"Yaxis":-0.79,"Zaxis":0.59,"WorldRegion":"NA","Country":"US","LocationText":"Ash Hill, NC","Location":"NA-US-NC-ASH HILL","Decommisioned":false,"TaxReturnsFiled":842,"EstimatedPopulation":1666,"TotalWages":28876493}
```

**Error msg below**

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:652)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:194)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
> at streamingApp$.main(streamingApp.scala:25)
> at streamingApp.main(streamingApp.scala)

Need help to read data from kafka topic.

Comment: issue is your setup

Comment: I would appreciate if you can help me in how to fix the setup

Comment: @RanLupovich, just created a pom.xml file under src folder. Configuration provided below:


`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the guide for spark streaming + kafka integration

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

You might be missing the artifact "spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12"